# Optimizing mysql my.cnf - memory usage is dangerously high

Tags: mysql, linux, performance, mariadb, database-tuning

I have tunet up mysql by following some tips on the internet.

but the websites are loading slow and time time-to-first-byte is very high. therefore i started investigation and as far as i see,  it is casued by mysql and high memory usage

every time i make changes to the my.cnf according to the suggestions i get from 
**./mysqltuner.pl** AND **./tuning-primer.sh**
it gives another suggestions.  Actually some values should have balance to each other.   I hope someone have an idea how to get high performance usage of mysql and in the same time, take care of the server health

**MariaDB server version: 10.0.20-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server**
Server information:
Intel Core i7-3770
2x HDD 3,0 TB SATA
4x RAM 8192 MB DDR3
Cloudlinux + Cpanel installed
Apache/2.4.16 + eAccelerator + mod_pagespeed

```
SLOW QUERIES
Error: slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log
Current long_query_time = 10.000000 sec.
You have 1944 out of 25401054 that take longer than 10.000000 sec. to complete
**Your long_query_time seems to be fine**

BINARY UPDATE LOG
The binary update log is NOT enabled.
**You will not be able to do point in time recovery**
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/10.0/en/point-in-time-recovery.html

WORKER THREADS
Current thread_cache_size = 8
Current threads_cached = 6
Current threads_per_sec = 0
Historic threads_per_sec = 0
**Your thread_cache_size is fine**

MAX CONNECTIONS
Current max_connections = 151
Current threads_connected = 6
Historic max_used_connections = 43
The number of used connections is 28% of the configured maximum.
**Your max_connections variable seems to be fine.**

No InnoDB Support Enabled!

MEMORY USAGE
Max Memory Ever Allocated : 20.96 G
Configured Max Per-thread Buffers : 24.81 G
Configured Max Global Buffers : 13.89 G
Configured Max Memory Limit : 38.70 G
Physical Memory : 31.12 G

**Max memory limit exceeds 90% of physical memory**

KEY BUFFER
Current MyISAM index space = 29 M
Current key_buffer_size = 384 M
Key cache miss rate is 1 : 870
Key buffer free ratio = 78 %
**Your key_buffer_size seems to be fine**

QUERY CACHE
Query cache is enabled
Current query_cache_size = 512 M
Current query_cache_used = 222 M
Current query_cache_limit = 1.00 G
Current Query cache Memory fill ratio = 43.41 %
Current query_cache_min_res_unit = 4 K
**MySQL won't cache query results that are larger than query_cache_limit in size**

SORT OPERATIONS
Current sort_buffer_size = 16 M
Current read_rnd_buffer_size = 8 M
**Sort buffer seems to be fine**

JOINS
./tuning-primer.sh: line 402: export: `2097152': not a valid identifier
Current join_buffer_size = 128.00 M
You have had 10199 queries where a join could not use an index properly
join_buffer_size >= 4 M
**This is not advised
You should enable "log-queries-not-using-indexes"
Then look for non indexed joins in the slow query log.**

OPEN FILES LIMIT
Current open_files_limit = 16162 files
The open_files_limit should typically be set to at least 2x-3x
that of table_cache if you have heavy MyISAM usage.
**Your open_files_limit value seems to be fine**

TABLE CACHE
Current table_open_cache = 8000 tables
Current table_definition_cache = 8000 tables
You have a total of 7347 tables
You have 8000 open tables.
**Current table_cache hit rate is 21%
, while 100% of your table cache is in use
You should probably increase your table_cache**

TEMP TABLES
Current max_heap_table_size = 16 M
Current tmp_table_size = 16 M
Of 592173 temp tables, 36% were created on disk
**Perhaps you should increase your tmp_table_size and/or max_heap_table_size
to reduce the number of disk-based temporary tables
Note! BLOB and TEXT columns are not allow in memory tables.
If you are using these columns raising these values might not impact your
ratio of on disk temp tables.**

TABLE SCANS
Current read_buffer_size = 16 M
Current table scan ratio = 74 : 1
**read_buffer_size is over 8 MB there is probably no need for such a large read_buffer**

TABLE LOCKING
Current Lock Wait ratio = 1 : 4366
**You may benefit from selective use of InnoDB.
If you have long running SELECT's against MyISAM tables and perform
frequent updates consider setting 'low_priority_updates=1'
If you have a high concurrency of inserts on Dynamic row-length tables
consider setting 'concurrent_insert=ALWAYS'.**

root@my [~]# ./mysqltuner.pl

 >>  MySQLTuner 1.4.0 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
[!!] Currently running unsupported MySQL version 10.0.20-MariaDB-log
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +Aria +BLACKHOLE +CSV +FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MyISAM
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 82M (Tables: 925)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 7G (Tables: 6334)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 52)
[--] Data in MEMORY tables: 0B (Tables: 2)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 159

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 14h 42m 18s (25M q [480.374 qps], 81K conn, TX: 71B, RX: 6B)
[--] Reads / Writes: 98% / 2%
[--] Total buffers: 13.9G global + 168.3M per thread (151 max threads)
**[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 38.7G (124% of installed RAM)**
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (1K/25M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 28% (43/151)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 384.0M/29.8M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 99.9% (12M cached / 14K reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 44.9% (20M cached / 44M selects)
**[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 2013573**
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (1K temp sorts / 1M sorts)
**[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 10207
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 58% (345K on disk / 592K total)**
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 98% (1K created / 81K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 21% (8K open / 38K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 12% (1K/16K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (10M immediate / 10M locks)
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 10.0G/7.7G
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0
-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    **Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Increasing the query_cache size over 128M may reduce performance
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses**
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    query_cache_size (> 512M) [see warning above]
    join_buffer_size (> 128.0M, or always use indexes with joins)
    tmp_table_size (> 16M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 16M)
```

And here is the my.cnf settings which i have set

```
[mysqld]
#http://blog.secaserver.com/2011/08/mysql-recommended-my-cnf-settings-innodb-engine/
# GENERAL #
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
tmpdir=/tmp_mysql
group_concat_max_len=10000000
local-infile=1

# LOGGING #
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log
long_query_time = 10
log-error = /var/log/error.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes

# CACHES AND LIMITS AND SAFETY #
max_allowed_packet = 512M #16
query_cache_size = 512M
query_cache_limit = 1024M
thread_cache_size = 8
table_definition_cache = 8000
table_open_cache = 8000
sort_buffer_size = 16M
read_buffer_size = 16M   #2
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
join_buffer_size = 128M
thread_concurrency = 0 # Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
key_buffer = 256M


# INNODB #
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_sort_buffer_size = 128M
innodb_data_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
innodb_thread_concurrency=0
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT 
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120
innodb_buffer_pool_size=10G
innodb_log_file_size = 1536M   # Set .. innodb_log_file_size to 25 % of innodb_buffer_pool_size -You can set .. innodb_buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
innodb_log_buffer_size = 3072M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
#innodb_read_io_threads=16
#innodb_write_io_threads=16
#innodb_io_capacity=500
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
#sync_binlog=1
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:2000M;ibdata2:10M:autoextend


# MyISAM #
key_buffer_size = 384M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M


[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Comment: Set `thread_concurrency` to 2 times cpu cores intel i7. You may want to optimise SELECT queries with LIMIT to optimise more. Further you may want to setup INDEXES in your database for faster queries. Don't forget to optimize and repair your database.

Comment: i have 8 CPUs, so i will set this to 16
what about the memory limitation,  do you have any suggestion to lower that and what to lower?

Comment: `LIMIT` does not speed up a query unless the index it is using goes covers all of the `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` (if any), _and_ `ORDER BY`.

Comment: `thread_concurrency` is specific to Solaris 8, and was deprecated in 5.6.1.  `innodb_thread_concurrency` is different, and tricky to set optimally.  `0` might be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary**

- Don't worry about the memory "problem"
- Look at the slowlog - you have some serious optimizations to deal with
- Why thousands of tables?  This is probably a design flaw.
- Ignore the comments about fragmentation.
- Convert the rest of your tables to InnoDB.

**Details**

> Your long_query_time seems to be fine

No, crank `long_query_time` down to 2 and keep an eye on the slow queries.

> No InnoDB Support Enabled!
>   [--] Data in InnoDB tables: 7G (Tables: 6334)

Those statments contradict each other!
InnoDB is the preferred engine.  The other outputs seem to say that InnoDB is in use.  (Bug in the script?)

> Max memory limit exceeds 90% of physical memory
>   [!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 38.7G (124% of installed RAM)

There is no forumla without flaws.  You are *probably* OK.

> Your key_buffer_size seems to be fine

The `key_buffer` should be the largest memory usage in a MyISAM_only server.  But you have a tiny database, so no problem.
The `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be the largest memory user when using InnoDB.
Your current values are good:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10G
key_buffer_size = 384M
```

> Current query_cache_size = 512 M
>   [OK] Query cache efficiency: 44.9% (20M cached / 44M selects)
>   [!!] Query cache prunes per day: 2013573

The 512M hurts performance; limit it to 50M.
The other two lines say that the QC is not that useful, and has a lot pruning overhead.
Conclusion:  Cautiously try

```
query_cache_size = 0
query_cache_type = OFF
```

> ./tuning-primer.sh: line 402: export: `2097152': not a valid identifier

Bug in the script?

> You should enable "log-queries-not-using-indexes"

No, it just clutters the slowlog. 
A one-line table with no index, or even a 100-row table with no index is likely to be "fast enough".
Instead, look at the existing slow queries to decide what should be worked on.

> You have a total of 7347 tables
>   (Tables: 6334)

That's a design flaw in your database.

> Of 592173 temp tables, 36% were created on disk

Again, the slowlog can help identify the worst queries.  Then we can work on fixing them, either by adding an index or by reformulating the query.

> [!!] Total fragmented tables: 159
>   Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables

Ignore -- virtually all tables are virtually always fragmented.  No action item here.

> [480.374 qps]

A good reason to go to InnoDB.

> [!!] Joins performed without indexes: 10207
>   [!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 58% (345K on disk / 592K total)**

Gotta see the slowlog entries.  Let's start with the 10 second ones you have already caught.

> `#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1`

Suggest setting to 2.

(This is the first time I have seen `tuning-primer.sh`; I am not impressed.)

These two blogs are likely to be useful:

- [MyISAM to InnoDB](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb)
- [Cookbook for creating INDEXes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: Hi Rick. Thanks alot for the detailed description.  I Will work on this and take Your suggestions In use.

Answer (score 0):

It seems more likely to be an incomplete indexing issue.

1. verify all fields in WHERE clause of slow queries to be indexed properly
2. if you have Nfields-in-one indexes try spreading them separately (if they make subject of separate condition) as only the first one will be really indexed or all N together one a WHERE clause
3. avoid redundant indexing (enum like cases or advanced bit)
4. db structure might need a little touch too - but this really depends on your db profile and of course the way data gets updated and viewed (you can improve using mixed type of engines per case - but you gotta know how to tweak your my.cnf properly)